# Rikulo stream base folder

Tags: stream, dart, rikulo

Is it possible to choose to serve files only from a specific folder using Rikulo stream? I've tried

```
new StreamServer(uriMapping: _mapping, homeDir: 'my/web/webapp/app')
```

but I'm not getting the desired results as it's still serving files under the 'web' directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When homeDir is specified with a relative path, it is assumed to be relative to the current directory (Directory.current.path). I think it is not what you expect. You can use an absolute path for better control.

After examining the code, I think the relative path is better to base on the root directory rather than the current directory. Please follow [Issue 29](https://github.com/rikulo/stream/issues/29) for details. Also refer to the sample app [here](https://github.com/rikulo/stream/tree/master/test/issue29).